# Displaying image from google drive in our website

Tags: javascript, image, iframe, same-origin-policy, x-frame-options

I want to display images that are in google drive into my Application using either `img tag` or an `Iframe`

The url looks like

> https://drive.google.com/a/xxxxxxx/file/d/1JOYDxgAssxNWukkTC_lkcY3qYQ_YmsSD/view?usp=drive_open (I didnt expose the real link due to security concerns)

I tried using `<img>` tag and also in `<iFrame>`

When used image tag, The image did not load, and when using Iframe, the error comes like

**Error with Iframe:**

> Refused to display
>   'https://drive.google.com/a/xxxxxxx/file/d/1JOYDxgAssxNWukkTC_lkcY3qYQ_YmsSD/view?usp=drive_open'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'. (I didnt expose the real link due to security concerns)

Any suggestion or help is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Did you make the document public ? [`Public Document G-Drive`](https://www.appypie.com/faqs/how-can-i-make-my-google-drive-document-public)

Comment: Yes, I can open that `url` from the browser, even without any google account login. So it is Public.